# Manipulate SQLite database located in program folder

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

I come from MySQL and I tried learning something of SQLite.I manually created a Database  and I put it in the program files (x86) folder. 
The connection doesn't have error, but when i create a table it gives me this error :

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CANTOPEN]  Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:825)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.exec(CoreStatement.java:75)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:61)
at SQLite.createDatabase(SQLite.java:15)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

This is my code :

```
    Connection cn;  
    try {
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodFiscExtractor\\database.db");
        Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (\n"
            + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
            + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
            + " capacity real\n"
            + ");");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I should do?

Comment: Have you load the db driver with `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`?

Comment: The problem seems to be the permission. This operation needs admin rights. Storing the database in a different path should solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be finally the permissions. It's an internally problem with windows...
You can start the java program with admin privileges to fix this bug. Alternate just store your local database in another path.

Also still load the drivers before connect to the database:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```